# CAS 6.4 REST Authentication to External Service - Missing type id property '@class'

Tags: rest, cas

I am trying to replace MongoAuthentication (cas-server-support-mongo) with RestAuthentication [(cas-server-support-rest-authentication)](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.4.x/authentication/Rest-Authentication.html). Here are what I achieved so far:

- Be able to ask CAS call to my external REST URI to authenticate the user.
- My REST URI is also be able to return data as CAS required. Here is the log I got. It seems to be OK at this step.

```
[36m2021-12-18 00:19:18,155 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.adaptors.rest.RestAuthenticationHandler] 
- <REST authentication response received
[{"_class":"org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.SimplePrincipal","id":"myemail@gmail.com","attributes":{}}]>
```

Here is the error CAS threw

```
ERROR [org.apereo.cas.adaptors.rest.RestAuthenticationHandler] 
- <Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.Principal]: 
missing type id property '@class'
```

I am pretty sure that my REST response has `id`

```
return {
    '@class': "org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.SimplePrincipal",
    'id': 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'attributes': {}
}
```

I tried all `@class` or `_class`. Both of them didn't work at all.

Finally. Cas said

```
Unable to detect the authentication principal for myemail@gmail.com
```

Could you please kindly advise what I forgot?

THanks,
Quang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand java, i have the same question, i just use the error log and read the document to try, maybe the json can help you

```
{
"@class": "org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.SimplePrincipal",
"id": "abc",
"attributes": {
    "@class": "java.util.LinkedHashMap",
    "username": [
        "java.util.List",
        ["jackson"]
    ]
 }
}
```

Comment: lol. Thank you so much bro. It worked for my case